# Why i can't use equal function for 2 string in windows form AP? it's always return False

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, textbox, equals

I wrote a simple windows_form application in c#, so I put some TextBox for some data and a DataGridView and a button that when user press key, my information in TextBoxes will copy to DataGridView. and my form has a TextBox for search when I wrote a string on it for search and click Just4Test button it returns always False value.can anyone explain why?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
dataGridView1[1, 0].ToString()
```

what do you get? Have you tried debugging? According to the [documentation `DataGridViewCell.ToString()` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.tostring.aspx):

> Unless otherwise noted, the ToString method for all the various cell types
>   will return a string of the form shown in the following code example:
>
> `Classname {RowIndex = #, ColumnIndex = #}`

I think you want something with `dataGridView1[1, 0].Value` instead.

Maybe similar to:

```
searchTextBox.Text == (string)dataGridView1[1, 0].Value
```

Comment: ''searchTextBox.Text == (string)dataGridView1[1, 0].Value'' it's worked but why previous version not worked? However thanks alot buddy

Comment: @saeedghasemi The problem before was that you were comparing a string that looked like `"gha"` to a string that looked like `"DataGridViewTextBoxCell {RowIndex = 1, ColumnIndex = 0}"`, or similar. You were forgetting the `.Value`. Your old approach could probably have worked with this: `dataGridView1[1, 0].Value.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

who knows what's different between 
    testi = searchTextBox.Text ==dataGridView1[1, 0].ToString();
and
    testi = searchTextBox.Text == (string)dataGridView1[1, 0].Value;
??

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer. You can delete the answer.